# Flushing LVL up when not as thick as wall?

Tags: framing, support

Can LVL beams be used with spacer blocks in the center to flush the LVL material up on each exterior side?  For example when using two 1-3/4" thick LVL's with 2x6 trimmer material it only comes out to 3.5", so can you use 2" spacer blocks between each LVL to flush them up? Or must they be glued & nailed together with an artificial spacer material on one side?

As backstory, there was no specification on whether the LVL needed to be sistered & nailed per typical LVL nail schematics from the engineer.  They didn't even ask the floor joist length which was bothersome. Both lumber yard and building department seemed okay with having the space in middle be hollow, but I was curious in terms of support if the LVL in a box header format functions differently. I don't see how because it's bearing equally on trimmer studs, and now has a larger footprint in terms of load point. Wanted to know if builders or engineers had third opinion.

Edit to add: Engineer okayed this. Said that technically one LVL was enough for the load. When I asked if this would work for two when needed he said "I don't see why not, as long as they can not separate from one another and touch at same points" which is what the structural lags and top plate above the LVL do.

Comment: Presumably you had an engineer specify the LVL size?

Comment: Yes, there was no specification on whether the LVL needed to be sistered & nailed per typical LVL nail schematics.  Both lumber yard and building department seemed okay with having the space in middle be hollow, but I was curious in terms of support if the LVL in a box header format functions differently. I don't see how because it's bearing equally, and now has a larger footprint in terms of load point.  Wanted to know if builders or engineers had third opinion.

Comment: Do you have the spec sheet from the LVL manufacturer? I’ve always seen the manufacturer require that individual members are nailed or bolted together for a built up beam.

Comment: @RibaldEddie yes, and I haven't seen a spec sheet where fastening multiple plies is *not* required

Comment: Is this a typical situation that LVL is used in parallel to a wall as the edge beam? What was the call out (of the edge beam) by the engineer, 2- 1 3/4" x XX" LVL?

Answer (score 3):

No, you wouldn't space out the beam members. They generally need to remain fixed together according to the fastener schedule provided by the manufacturer or architect. You'd then fur out to the thickness of the wall. Even if this isn't a requirement, it's what I'd do. You don't want to have to try and tie heavy members together with fasteners when they're spread.

It's common practice to put the beam flush to one face of the wall, mostly so you don't have to fur out both and possibly insulate between. Add whatever lumber strips are convenient. A few fasteners will not cause structural concerns.

Comment: Yes, "They generally need to remain fixed together" is my understanding too, with sometimes allowance for a 1/2in plywood sandwich up to make things flush, but what do you mean with "You don't want to have to try and tie heavy members together with fasteners"?

Comment: Edited to clarify. Usually when beams are doubled it's required that they be connected mechanically using appropriate fasteners. The new beam then becomes greater than the sum of the parts in terms of load rating. If you space them out you'd have to come up with the equivalent fastener of a much longer length, and you'd have to provide spacer blocks that are structurally suitable. I wouldn't risk degrading beam performance with such an approach, as a matter of best practice if not specific requirement.

Comment: I've always done this as well but I'm very curious what the difference is in a situation where each LVL is bearing the same? There is a flat top plate above the lvl that holds the top of the lvl from pulling out, blocks in the center void with structural lags, and then the bottoms are secured to the load bearing posts on each end. The footprint of weight is now distributed more equally than if one side of the wall had both lvl flushed up.

Comment: Weight distribution isn't really a concern here. They're on the same trimmer studs or posts, and it doesn't really matter where they sit. There are certainly many ways to secure the beams. I'm only relating common practice. Where twin LVLs are specified they usually have an attachment schedule. YMMV.

Comment: Headers in exterior walls have their cavity on the inside rather than between the plies so that insulation can be applied *after* framing. Multiple plies of beams are fastened to each other to handle side loads (joist or beam hangers); also if point loaded by joists/cross-beams/posts, *I believe* to avoid buckling along the depth or shifting of the plies, causing one ply to bare more load than the other.

Comment: My family typically built our exterior wall headers in a U-configuration and insulated them before installation. This preserved backing over the window for trim, window treatments, etc.

Comment: isherwood I agree, I see most LVL documents showing the plies nailed together. I would do this in a traditional beam (like basement) or like @P2000 mentioned when having joist hangers used, because then you literally are only bearing weight on ONE of the TWO LVL members.  However in this scenarior, where a top plate is apply even surface area to two identical LVL (bearing on trimmers at same points) I do not feel nearly as concerned.  I also like foam in middle for exterior headers. A 2x6 wall allows this.

Comment: "I also like foam in middle" what kind of foam? If not XPS, will it breathe and where is the vapour barrier?